# yum was work well but after install cpanel on server yum cant do anything

Tags: cpanel, yum, whm

yum was work well  but after install  cpanel  on server yum cant do anything 
and this error

cpanel-addons-production-feed                            | 2.9 kB     00:00
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://httpupdate.cpanel.net/cpanel-plugins-clatest-x86_64-mirrorlist error was
14: HTTP Error 404 - Not Found

One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

```
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
    just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
    --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

 4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: cpanel-plugins/latest/x86_64

Comment: Welcome to SO, it might help to read [tour] .  This question probably belongs at the sister site ServerFault.com or maybe unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

After many days ,I found the answer by my self. 

 Here is the solution 

1.After installing the cpanel you have to immediately run the command>

**/scripts/configure_firewall_for_cpanel**

2. Done